# A smooth function germ not coming from an analytic function germ?

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question

This is a soft question.

As I understand it, [Borel's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%27s_lemma) implies that, given any sequence of real numbers $(a_n)_{n\geq 0}$, the formal power series

$$ \sum_{n\geq 0} a_nx^n $$

is the Taylor expansion at the origin of *some* smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Apply this with a sufficiently fast-growing sequence $a_n$ such that the radius of convergence of the series is zero, for example $a_n = n!$, yielding some *smooth* function $f$ with $(d^nf/dx^n)_{x=0} = n!^2$.

I am having trouble understanding $f$. Evidently, it cannot be analytic. Fine, there are many smooth functions that are not analytic. But the main examples of such in my mind (e.g. $e^{-1/x^2}$ at $x=0$) are locally approximated by analytic functions, in the sense that at any given point there is an analytic function with the same power series expansion. The $f$ in question is smooth but is not locally approximated by an analytic function (at $x=0$, the relevant point) in this sense.

> What does $f$'s too-fast-growing Taylor expansion force it to look like around $x=0$?

Apologies again that this is a soft question. Something is bothering me, and I'm not exactly sure what type of information would resolve the dissonance. (That said, I could imagine a complete/precise answer consisting of pointing out to me something important I am missing.)

**Remark:** Another framework for what's going on. Borel's lemma asserts that the map $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}[[x]]$ sending a smooth function to its Taylor expansion at $0$ is surjective. In fact, this map is well-defined on the ring $C_{x=0}^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ of germs of smooth functions at $x=0$, and $C_{x=0}^\infty(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow \mathbb{R}[[x]]$ is surjective by Borel's lemma. Now we can restrict this map to the germs of *analytic* functions, each defined on some (arbitrarily small) neighborhood of $x=0$. Then, the above reasoning is saying it stops being surjective (although the image is evidently still dense since germs of even just polynomials map to polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[[x]]$, and these are dense). What do the functions representing smooth germs that are not analytic germs look like? (Note that the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1306972/germs-of-smooth-functions-vs-germs-of-analytic-functions) is not what I'm looking for. In that question, the key point was that an analytic germ may not extend to a global analytic function [and therefore you can't construct the whole ring of analytic germs by beginning with the global analytic functions]. Here I am interested in the smooth germs that do not come from analytic germs at all.)

Comment: Construct a smooth function $g$ with the same Taylor expansion at $0$ then $f-g$ is smooth and all its derivatives vanish at $0$, ie. $f-g = o(x^k)$ for all $k$.

Comment: @reuns - I am not sure how that is relevant? It seems to me such a $g$ will be mysterious exactly in the way $f$ is mysterious.

Comment: Not really, you can [construct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%27s_lemma) such a $g$

Comment: @reuns - That is the very lemma I am using to construct $f$ in the first place. I see no difference between my $f$ and your $g$. That said, it is a soft question, so I apologize that what I am asking for is not more clear.

Comment: What do you mean with "I see no difference between $f$ and $g$" ? $g$ is a canonical representative of the smooths functions whose Taylor series at $0$ is the same as $f$'s, this set is very large and it is characterized by : $h$ is smooth and $\forall k, f-h = o(x^k)$ as $x \to 0$

Comment: $f$ was constructed in the OP by a call to Borel's lemma, same as you constructed $g$. They may well be the same function.

Comment: (I do not see that the construction is canonical as it involves e.g. a choice of bump function, can you clarify the canonical claim? That might help me.)

Comment: What do you want more ? Canonical in the sense that there is deterministic algorithm generating some $g$ from any Taylor series. Are you really asking to construct all the smooth functions whose Taylor series at $0$ is identically $0$ ? It is not very different to constructing all the smooth functions.

Comment: Perhaps I am misreading the proof of Borel's lemma in the link, but it appears to involve the choice of a bump function, so the construction is not deterministic. What am I missing?

Comment: Fix a bump function. Also note the smooth functions on $\Bbb{R/Z}$ whose all derivatives vanish at $0$ are isomorphic (through $\tan \pi x$) to the Schwartz space and the Hermite functions makes it isomorphic to the set of rapidly decreasing sequences, thus we can generate all the smooth functions on $\Bbb{R/Z}$ with prescribed Taylor series at $0$.